# How to make tbody width == table width?

Tags: html, css

How do I make tbody within my table equal to the table width? I want to remove the margins, but

```
tbody{
    margin: 0%;
}
```

does nothing. I want to highlight a table data cell when the user hovers over it with its cursor. I have managed that, but there is a visible border between the data cell and the table row. How do I remove this border or margin?

Here is the CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0%;
}
header{
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
nav{
    background-color: red;
}
div.nav_div{
    background-color: blue;
}

table{
    margin: auto;   
}
tbody, tr{
    margin: 0ch;
    border-width: 0ch;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0%;
}
table tr td{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 0%;
}
td{
    padding-inline: 120px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
td:hover{
    background-color: chartreuse;
}
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Place Title Here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<!-- place html web page content here -->
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="nav_div">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div>
                words
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
<script>
// Place JavaScript Code Here
"use strict";

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're looking for the [`border-collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) property.

Comment: Can you provide the css you are using for the data cell hover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`border-collapse` only applies to `<table>` there is very little in the way of CSS properties applied directly to `<tbody>` or `<tr>` if any. When applied correctly (ie to `<table>`), each border of `<table>`, `<th>`, and `<td>` will merge into a single border with it's neighboring border thereby eliminating any space between `<table>`, `<th>`, and `<td>`. See example. Also, I added `min-width: max-content` to `<header>` because the `<table>`'s width exceeded everything (`inline-padding: 120px` makes each cell at least 240px wide, so a width of at least 720px).

```css
body {
  margin: 0%;
}

header {
  min-width: max-content;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

nav {
  background-color: red;
}

div.nav_div {
  background-color: blue;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-inline: 120px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: chartreuse;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav_div">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div>
      words
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `fill-available` [fill-available](https://caniuse.com/?search=fill-available). Note that the code doesn't run well in this snippet, you can bring it to your page to check if it work.

> Allows for the heights and widths to be specified in intrinsic values using the max-content, min-content, fit-content and stretch (formerly fill) properties.

```
    table {
        width: -moz-available;          /* WebKit-based (Chrome, etc) browsers will ignore this. */
        width: -webkit-fill-available;  /* Firefox - Mozilla-based browsers will ignore this. */
        width: fill-available;
    }
```

But in my opinion, to achieve what you want, you can use [Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead. it's  more flexible and easy to tweak

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.child {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.child:hover {
  background-color: chartreuse;
}

body {
  margin: 0%;
}

header {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

nav {
  background-color: red;
}

div.nav_div {
  background-color: blue;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
}

tbody,
tr {
  margin: 0ch;
  border-width: 0ch;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0%;
}

table tr td {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0%;
}

td {
  padding-inline: 120px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Place Title Here</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- place html web page content here -->
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav_div">
        <div class="parent">
          <div class="child">1</div>
          <div class="child">2</div>
          <div class="child">3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        words
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <script>
    // Place JavaScript Code Here
    " use strict ";
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```